# Angularjs Resource Object a.push is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have created a resource object:

```
factory('TextResource', 
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(adminBaseUrl+'/texts/:type', {}, {
            create: {method: 'POST', params: {type:'create'}, headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}},
            update: {method: 'POST', params: {type:'update'}, headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}},
            query: {method: 'GET', params: {type: 'list'}},
            remove: {method: 'POST', params: {type: 'remove'}, headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}},
            getText: {method: 'GET', params: {type: 'get', id:'@id'}}
        });
    }
)
```

And my controller is:

```
controller('EditText', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'TextResource', 'HttpStatusMessage',
    function($scope, $location, $routeParams, TextResource, HttpStatusMessage) {
        $scope.alerts = [];
        $scope.languages = [];

        TextResource.getText(
            {id: $routeParams.id},
            function(data) {
                $scope.languages = data.result;
            },
            function(error) {
                var httpError = new HttpStatusMessage(error.status);
                $scope.alerts.push({type:'error', msg:httpError.msg});
            });

        $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
            $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
        }

        $scope.submit = function() {
            TextResource.update(
                $scope.languages,
                function(data) {
                    if( data.type == 'success' ) {
                        $location.path('texts');
                    } else {
                        $scope.alerts.push({type:data.type, msg:data.message});
                    }
                },
                function(error) {
                    var httpError = new HttpStatusMessage(error.status);
                    $scope.alerts.push({type:'error', msg:httpError.msg});
                });
        }

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $location.path('texts');
        }
    }
])
```

The response i am getting from TextResource.getText request is:

```
{"result":[{"id":"3","value":"This is my first text<br>","key":"my_first_text","language_id":"1","name":"English"},{"id":"3","value":"Ceci est mon premier texte","key":"my_first_text","language_id":"3","name":"French"}],"num_rows":2}
```

Now when i click on submit it displays the error:

```
Error: a.push is not a function
```

The response object contains 2 keys result and num_rows result is an array. The reason i am not using isArray parameter in resource object is in case if any error occured in server like session time out, access not allowed etc. the server returned a object contains error msg.

Comment: search your code where 'a.push' is ?

Comment: a.push is written in angularjs file

Comment: I can see non of your actions has defined 'isArray', have you tried setting it ? . isArray – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this action is an array, see returns section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by modifying the update function like:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
            TextResource.update(
                {'language':$scope.languages},
                function(data) {
                    if( data.type == 'success' ) {
                        $location.path('texts');
                    } else {
                        $scope.alerts.push({type:data.type, msg:data.message});
                    }
                },
                function(error) {
                    var httpError = new HttpStatusMessage(error.status);
                    $scope.alerts.push({type:'error', msg:httpError.msg});
                });
        }
```

I was directly posting an array in update which throws the error. So encapsulating in another key solved the problem.